# UIWebView - Scheme unknown

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need some help handling some `NSData` object within an `UIWebView`. Tapping a link inside `UIWebView` cause a `NSLog` entry:

```
Scheme unkown, doing nothing: <URL>
```

That is what I did:

I start an external `HTTPGetOperation` to get a response of URL-request. I need to do so because of handling to download files. The response is stored to an `NSData` object.

Then I load that data within a method that is called when `HTTPGetOperation` is done:

```
[myWebView loadData:myNSDataObject MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

So far, `UIWebView` shows the content of `myNSDataObject` correctly.

But, when I try to tap a link inside that content I get a `NSLog` entry "Unknown scheme, doing nothing: " with the URL of the link.

Notice: After tapping a link the delegate methods like `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` are not called.

Notice: the delegate is set to `[self.myWebView setDelegate:self]`

Which methods creates that `NSLog` entry?

Why are the delegate methods are not called after tapping a link?

Does anyone knows an answer?

Answer (score 1):

How are the links coded? Are they http:// links or are they custom? As long as the link is in standard form, the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method can test the URL scheme to determine how it should be handled.

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - 44.0f)];
webView.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"mycustomdata"]) {
        // insert your code here to actually load the correct data
        return NO;
    }
}
```

If your delegate isn't getting called, then you have some other issue. I would also recommend implementing didFailLoadWithError, webViewDidFinishLoad, and webViewDidStartLoad.